# How to set .InitialView and see files when using FileDialogFolderPicker?

Tags: vba, filedialog

I want open a dialog where the user can:

- select a folder
- sort entries alphabetically
- see files as well as folders

I'm trying to use VBA's Application.FileDialog to accomplish this, current code as follows:

```
Sub makeFileDialog()

Dim dialog As FileDialog
Dim result As String


Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With dialog
    .InitialFileName = "c:\"
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
    If dialog.Show = -1 Then
        result = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    Else
        result = ""
    End If
End With

debug.print result

End Sub
```

This lets me select a folder, but the `.InitialView` isn't properly set--the views button is grayed out, and the folder list isn't divided into columns for sorting.  I think maybe `.InitialView` can't be set with `msoFileDialogFolderPicker`.  Also, no filenames show up.

I tried changing `FileDialog`'s parameter to `msoFileDialogFilePicker`, which let me use views and showed files, but with that I can't select and return a folder.

I saw a solution online that uses the `CreateObject("Shell.Application")`, but the dialog created by the shell isn't very flexible and doesn't offer much information about each file.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. There is not way to allow a user to select either a folder or file. I think most would agree that this is a good thing.

You have it right - use **msoFileDialogFilePicker** to show all folders and files. You can, if you so desire, just use the filepicker, and parse the file name to get the folder path if you really need to.